# Unable to send Email through GoDaddy SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, smtp, smtpclient

I am working on an ASP .Net MVC website and I've to send email through Godaddy smtp, **Previously my site was developed in classic ASP and it was hosted on godaddy's web hosting (then it was working fine) but now I am hosting this site on IIS**,

I am using following code to send email but it is not working

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress(model.From);
msg.To.Add(model.To);
msg.Body = model.Body;
msg.Subject = model.Subject;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net",25);
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("support@{myCompanyName}.com",{password});
smtp.EnableSsl  = False;
smtp.Send(msg);
```

I have also used ***dedrelay.secureserver.net*** instead of ***relay-hosting.secureserver.net*** host (as mentioned at https://pk.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-servers-email-relay-server-16601) but both are not working

Comment: So now you are not on godaddy's server?

Comment: No now I am hosting my site on IIS server on a personal system

Comment: It may be possible that from their server they allowed a un-ecrypted port 25 access from outside they might be only allowing SSL access, please just telnet confirm that

Comment: did you check that smtp client is reachable from you machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoDaddy does not allow relaying through their server unless you are on one of their hosting plans that includes SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your credentials in webconfig like (for godaddy)

```
 <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="your email address">
      <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and in c# you can use like

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("your email address");

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("your recipient"));

message.Subject = "your subject";
message.Body = "content of your email";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

It will work

Comment: GoDaddy does not handle mail for non-customers. There is no programming work-around for this. They simply will not handle your mail unless you pay them.

Answer (score 1):

Most SMTP servers are quite restrictive nowadays when it comes to outbound email. I recommend testing the parameters with an email client (or telnet, if you're into that kinda thing) before assuming that there is something wrong with the code. That might also give you an error message that helps debugging.

Some things that come to mind:

1. The server may check the FROM address against it's database, specifically the user account you use to authenticate. While you can put whatever you want in the header of the email, this field must be your the real address of the authenticated account and only that (no descriptive name).
2. The server may require the use of TLS encryption, regardless of the port.
3. Port 25 is quite common, but according to the official RFC mail submission should use port 587. Maybe try that.
4. It is possible that GoDaddy only allows connections from their own (hosting) servers to these SMTP relays.

Unless the connection fails completely (which would point to no. 4) the server should send some kind of error message at some point. As I wrote above, I would recommend testing/logging the communication, that should provide some insight.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should call up to your ISP, here in th Netherlands they mostly block port 25 because of malware and worms that used to send out email. It can be as simple as this. Have you tried telnetting from your local machine to the email server (telnet mailserver.io 25)? If this ends up in a time out you have your answer and the port is either filtered out at your ISP or from their end.

Answer (score 1):

1. **You can try this code**

   ```
     smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";    smtp.EnableSsl = false;    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;    smtp.Port = 25;
   ```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        string From = "[MyGodaddyEMailAddress]"; //eg.info@mango.com
        string FromPassword = "[MyGodaddyMailPassword]";
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(From);
            msg.To.Add("[RecipientEmailAddress]");
            msg.Subject = "[MailSubject]";
            msg.Body = "[MailBody]";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.[domain].com", 587); //eg. mail.mango.com
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(From, FromPassword);

            smtp.EnableSsl = false;

            // Sending the email
            smtp.Send(msg);
            // destroy the message after sent
            msg.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Message Sent Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```